# WPF Hierarchical Treeview: Combined binding of a selfrefering hierarchical and a flat source

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, treeview, hierarchical-data, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Recently, I learned a lot about MVVM / Binding / Entityframework etc. And as I always go for the hard way - I use VB.NET - and have to convert most of the code found from C# to VB.NET ;) 
So, what's my Topic:

**Complete Titel:**

WPF Hierarchical Treeview: Combined binding and templating of an selfrefering hierarchical source and a flat source with EntityFramework 6 and Database First Approach.

**DataModel:**

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIb1v.png

**Expected Treeview**

I have two types of Items:

- "Dimensions" are  from a selfrefering Source (XELL_DIMENSION) and
  hierarchical Items. unknown/open Leveldepth.
- "Elements" are from a flat Source (XELL_ELEMENTS) a

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeFwe.png

Ok here's what I have achieved so far:

**Mainwindow Class:**

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Dim elementsContext As New XELLEntities()
        Tree.DataContext = elementsContext.XELL_DIMENSION.Include("XELL_ELEMS").ToList()
        Tree.ItemsSource = elementsContext.XELL_DIMENSION.Where(Function(y) y.DIMEN_PARENT_ID Is Nothing).ToList()
End Sub
```

**XAML CODE:**

```
 <TreeView Name="Tree" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="187" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="415">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:XELL_DIMENSION}" ItemsSource="{Binding DIM_ALL_NODE}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DIMEN_ID}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DIMEN_BEZ_LONG}"/>
                            <ListBox Name="Listy" ItemsSource="{Binding XELL_ELEMS}" DisplayMemberPath="ELEM_BEZ_LONG" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"/>
                        </StackPanel>                            
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>                           
        </TreeView>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Question:**

So that's the closest I came and I used a Listbox for the Elements - but this
is no solution to me.

**- How do I solve my Problem?**

I am thankful for any CodeSnipped provided.

Comment: will work on it and let u know very soon

Comment: Thank you - see my answer - it's solved for me - let me know if you come up with a more elegant way to do;)

Answer (score 1):

## **Eureka! -SOLVED**

I had to use a Converter and a TemplateSelector.

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView Name="Tree" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="187" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="415"> <TreeView.Resources>
            <local3:LeafDataTemplateSelector x:Key="LeafDataTemplateSelector" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local2:XELL_DIMENSION}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LeafDataTemplateSelector}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SimpleFolderConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="DIM_ALL_NODE" />
                        <Binding Path="XELL_ELEMS" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" Source="MVVM/VIEW/IMAGES/Nodes.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FF3399FF" Text="{Binding DIMEN_BEZ_LONG}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate> <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Dimension" DataType="{x:Type local2:XELL_DIMENSION}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LeafDataTemplateSelector}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SimpleFolderConverter}">
                       <Binding Path="XELL_ELEMS" />
                        <Binding Path="DIM_ALL_NODE" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <StackPanel Height="25" Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="Installation File">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" Source="MVVM/VIEW/IMAGES/Nodes.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FF3399FF" Text="{Binding DIMEN_BEZ_LONG}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate> <DataTemplate x:Key="Element" DataType="{x:Type local2:XELL_ELEMENT}">
                <StackPanel Height="25" Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="Installation File">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" Source="MVVM/VIEW/IMAGES/Shape57.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                       <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGray" Text="{Binding ELEM_BEZ_LONG}" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

**VB.NET - MainWindow**

```
    Public Sub New()
        ' Dieser Aufruf ist für den Designer erforderlich.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Fügen Sie Initialisierungen nach dem InitializeComponent()-Aufruf hinzu.

    End Sub

     Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

        Dim elementsContext As New XELLEntities()
        Tree.DataContext = elementsContext.XELL_DIMENSION.Include("XELL_ELEMS").ToList()
        Tree.ItemsSource = elementsContext.XELL_DIMENSION.Where(Function(y) y.DIMEN_PARENT_ID Is Nothing).ToList()


    End Sub
```

***VB.NET TemplateSelection***

```
    Public Class LeafDataTemplateSelector
    Inherits DataTemplateSelector
    Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As DependencyObject) As DataTemplate
        Dim element As FrameworkElement = TryCast(container, FrameworkElement)

        If element IsNot Nothing AndAlso item IsNot Nothing Then

            If TypeOf item Is XELL_DIMENSION Then
                Return TryCast(element.FindResource("Dimension"), DataTemplate)
            ElseIf TypeOf item Is XELL_ELEMENT Then
                Return TryCast(element.FindResource("Element"), DataTemplate)
            End If
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

**VB.NET Hierarchy Converter**

```
Class HierarchyConverter : Implements IValueConverter
    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim node = TryCast(value, Employee)
        If node IsNot Nothing Then
            Return node.Subordinates.Where(Function(i) i.ManagerID = node.EmployeeID).ToList()
        Else
        End If
    End Function 
Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotSupportedException
    End Function End Class
```

Hope this helps somebody ;)

Comment: good job done ! honestly i forgot your question. will still look at it.